# The better implementation of 2D dynamic array-like container in C#

Tags: c#

I gotta define a data structure for my computational modelings, as 2D array. As it could be guess, the first concern would be the performance in view of initialization, iteration and so on.
I have below ideas for above requirement:

```
IList<IList<MyClass>>
```

and

```
IList<MyClass> [,]
```

I am prone to know the technical differences between two mentioned options. Moreover, one might try to convince me in order to choose among the better one...

Comment: `IList<MyClass> [,]` is actually a 2-dimensional array of `IList<MyClass>` objects... i.e. a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: The first one is a list of lists, the second one is a 2-dimensional array of lists – they are not really the same.

Comment: It might be totally awesome if one can enlighten me more precisely about them...

Comment: Does your model have fixed dimensions, known before initialization?

Comment: @spender: My model is a spiking neural network... the first dimension is the index of the neuron, where as the total number of the neurons are not known, it is not fixed... the second index should be dedicated to time slice... The case is dynamic, totally.

Comment: @matinking : so this presents an issue: either you deal with the nasty business of resizing your collection (with 1:1 mapping with coordinate locations) when you exceed existing bounds, or you go for a sparse representation. Assume the array is to map connections between any pair of items, so most/all locations will be filled, right?

Comment: I might be tempted by a `Dictionary<Dictionary<int, MyClass>>` in this scenario.

Comment: @spender: Your conclusion sounds reasonable, as all of the locations must be filled within the process... However, I didn't realize the rationality behind your dictionary-based suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you effectively need a map without fixed dimensions, it might be best to use dictionaries as your underlying data type so that you don't need to spend too much time thinking about resizing.

As such you could use a structure such as this:

```
class Map<T>
{
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>> map = 
         new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>>();
    public T this[int row,int column]
    {
        get { 
            Dictionary<int, T> rowDic;
            if(!map.TryGetValue(row,out rowDic))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            T val;
            if(!rowDic.TryGetValue(column, out val))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            return val;
        }
        set {
            Dictionary<int, T> rowDic;
            if(!map.TryGetValue(row,out rowDic))
            {
                map[row] = new Dictionary<int, T>();
            }
            map[row][column] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

so now you can use it just like a 2d array:

```
var map = new Map<string>();
map[88,33] = "foo";
```

Comment: @I am appreciated for your coherent and effective contribution... I need some time to understand the proposed type, to the bone :)

Comment: Of course, you might prefer to use a list of lists as your backing field here, because it has lower memory requirements.